# Equivalence of UTM

Tags: set-theory, turing-machines

What is the cardinality of the set of languages accepted by an Universal Turing Machine?

Is it $\aleph_0$ or $\aleph_1$?

What is the cardinality of the set of languages accepted by a Turing Machine?

Are any two Turing machines equivalent?

Are any two Universal Turing machines equivalent (what does it mean to be equivalent)?

Comment: Hint: how many TMs are there?

Answer (score 0):

It's $\aleph_0$ since the cardinality of the set of all Turing-machines is $\aleph_0$ and with each Turing-machine we can associate exactly one language that it accepts.

Now, it is perfectly possible for two different Turing-machines to accept the same language, in which case we can call them equivalent. But what is true is that there are *at most* as many languages as there are Turing-machines.

To show that the set of languages is *actually* $\aleph_0$, you would therefore have to do a bit more work, but you can easily show that for any $n$, there is a Turing-machine that accepts the language $\alpha^n$ with $\alpha$ a symbol. So, you have as many languages that can be accepted by Turing-machines as there are natural numbers, so the set of language is at least $\aleph_0$, and since we already established that it is at most $\aleph_0$, it is $\aleph_0$.

As far as Universal Turing machines go:

There are multiple reasonable ways to represent Turing-machines and their input on a tape, so you could have many different Universal Turing-machines that would not be considered equivalent since the 'language' they accept would differ according to the convention used. If you fix the convention, however, then while there can still be multiple Universal Turing-machines, their overall input-output behavior will be the same, and hence they accept the same language, and are equivalent.

Comment: I thought Turing machine is an one dimensional tape with heads. And that it can do 'all' possible computations and not just a specified one. Am I making a mistake?

Comment: @Robut You are probably thinking of a Universal Turing machine that can be given a program of any other Turing-machine. But any *specific* Turing machine really only accepts one language. Indeed, the same is true for a universal Turing-machine, though the 'language' is not your 'typical' language anymore.

Comment: Updated query mildly (could you please clarify?)

Comment: @Robut OK, I addressed the equivalence question as well. It actually improved the original answer, so that was a good update!

Comment: but you have not provided how to show two UTMs are equivalent ($2\Bbb N$ and $2\Bbb N+1$ have same cardinality but they are different sets)?

Comment: @Robut To show how two UTM's are equivalent you need to show how for every input they give the same output.  ... And yes: those two sets are different, but have the same cardinality .. but I am not sure what you are getting at with that ... Maybe this: the set of all languages is of course not the same as the set of all Turing-machines .. but they do have the same cardinality.

Comment: I just thought we cannot say two UTMs are same if the set of languages they accept have same cardinality. In general how to show two UTMs are equivalent? could you please supply a proof?

Comment: @Robut  UTM's don't have any cardinality at all ... they are not sets.  And I can't really show you how two UTM's are equivalent ... you would have to show that one a case by case basis, showing how every input would lead to the same output for these two machines. Although one way to show that is that whatever steps the one machine makes, the other machines makes as well ... though possibly in a more roundabout fashion ... and vice versa.